# Is there a Perl class or structure similar to .net SortedList or SortedCollection?

Tags: .net, perl

For anyone who is familiar with both Perl and .net, I'm looking for a data structure or class in Perl that maintains a sorted list.

The .net SortedList and SortedCollection classes take care of maintaining the sorting "behind the scenes".

When I search for Perl sorted list, the examples seem to use explicit calls to the sort function.

Is there any Perl library or add-on that approximates .net's Sorted classes?

Comment: You are confused. These are .net classes rather than Delphi classes.

Comment: I didn't know about .net, but Delphi does have this - I just forgot the class name. "Sorted" is a property, not part of the name. 
  MyNamelist := TStringList.Create;
  MyNamelist.sorted := true;
  MyNamelist.Duplicates := dupError;      
  MyNamelist.LoadFromFile('somefile.txt');

Comment: You listed the names of .net classes. You've got to use the right names for us to know what you mean.

Comment: Actually TSortedCollection was a class back in the Borland Pascal days....

Comment: Your question named SortedList and SortCollection. There was no TSortedCollection.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, a quick search for [tie sorted on CPAN](https://metacpan.org/search?q=tie%20sorted) produces [Tie::Array::Sorted](https://metacpan.org/pod/Tie%3a%3aArray%3a%3aSorted) and  [Tie::Hash::Sorted](https://metacpan.org/pod/Tie%3a%3aHash%3a%3aSorted), which seem to do exactly what you're asking for.  I don't have any experience with either.

Comment: Thanks, that should work. I am not familiar with the term "Tie". I need to study that.

Comment: [tie](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/tie.html) is the function that associates extra behavior with a Perl variable.